# setBadgeValue not working in AppDelegate.m (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar, appdelegate, badge

In my AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` BOOL I am calling this method:

```
UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard3Inch" bundle:nil];


UITabBarController *tabBarController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
[[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:@"2"];
```

I thought that now, during the App Launch, a badge would be set.
But no badge is displayed!

Storyboard ID is set @ the TabBarViewController.

And I also tried `instantiateInitialViewController` instead of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"`.

Can someone help?